# Access phpunit group parameter inside bootstrap

Tags: php, phpunit, bootstrapping

I am using `phpunit` to test a large php project.  The tests are organised in groups using `@group` annotation.  I also have a `phpunit.xml` file in the root directory of my tests, which, among other things, specifies the bootstrap php file.  In that file, I perform some general initialisation before running the tests.

I can run phpunit on the whole project by simply executing `phpunit` or I can run it for individual groups with `phpunit --group ...` command.  So far, so good.

Now I want my initialisation inside the bootstrap.php to do different things depending on the group that was specified when phpunit was invoked.  Yet I cannot find any information on how to access that data inside my bootstrap.  Is there any way to find out inside my boostrap.php whether `--group ...` parameter has been passed and, if yes, what the `...` value was specified?

**Update:** I'm running on PHP 5.5 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Why is this tagged 'bootstrap'?

Comment: @amphetamachine Why not?  Read the description of the tag.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Boostrap is a widely misused tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I gave up a bit too early.  All of the parameters are passed inside `$_SERVER['argv']`, hence

```
print_r($_SERVER['argv']);
```

produces something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /usr/bin/phpunit
    [1] => --group
    [2] => abc
)
```